# Печать HTML с большими картинками

Tags: print, html

Добрый день
Ситуация такая:
Есть страничка с заголовком, затем идёт большая картинка. Примерно так.

```
<html> 
    <head> 
    </head> 
    <body onload="window.print();">         
        <h1>Заголовок</h1>
        <img src="djvu_png.png"/> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

Так как картинка весьма большая всё сводится к тому, что заголовок остается на 1-ой страничке, а вторая страничка содержит картинку. Получается, что первая страничка почти пустая. Можно ли как-то насильно картинку вытащить на 1-ую страничку и при необходимости её уменьшить? Или есть какие-то еще варианты? Большое спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать для этого css:

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
   @page {
       width: xxx;
       height: yyy;
   }
</style>
```

Ширину и высоту подберите сами.

Answer (score 0):

Ну попробуйте процентно задать ей высоту

```
<img src="djvu_png.png" height="80%"/>
```

Ну или с размером ещё поиграйтесь.